# How to customize UI portal using React Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, customization

I need to develop UI portal in React js where 2 types of users are there, Admin , end user.
Now admin user customize the UI portal so that every user has different UI pages.

Admin can modify the followings,

1. Change the page layout
2. Header/footer adjustment
3. Banner adjustment
4. Search bar adjustment
5. Change color of the page

Not able to figure it out How should I approach in React js or is there any other technology need to introduce here.

Comment: You wont get far with only Reactjs. You will have to make your own backend with a connection to a Database because you have role administration and user relevant settings. Try it with an express server and connect it to a mongodb database. There are planty tutorials for it. Just search for "mern stack tutorial"

Comment: This is not inly the React js the Backend is present. I just need the help How can I customize the UI from Admin portal.

Comment: can any one help me on this requirement to build mini web site builder using React?